# git review doesn't work? but I am able to see my changes when I do a push. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git

I am using git and gerrit. After changing my files, I do the following:

1. git status
2. git add -> the modified files.
3. git commit -m "the commit message"
4. git review
5. git push

When I go git review: I get the following error message "No '.gitreview' file found in this repository. We don't know where your gerrit is. Please manually create a remote named gerrit and try again.

But when I do git push, I can see all my changes on the remote.i.e. the commit is made there. But I am not sure what's wrong.

Any thoughts or leads appreciated.

I already created gerrit when I was installing git/gerrit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The gerrit command `git review` expects that you have a remote repository set up named `gerrit`. If you already have your repository as a remote named origin (the default from a `git clone`), you can rename it to what git review expects with this:

`git remote rename origin gerrit`

Answer (score 6):

Before using `git review` you should configure the remote repository name. It's defaulted to `gerrit`. But you might want to change this default to `origin` as most repositories are called `origin`.

Simply call:

```
git config --global --add gitreview.remote origin
```

You might want to remove `--global` if it only applies for a single project.

This works for version 1.2.5 or newer.

---

For versions 1.2.4 or earlier add a gitreview config file: `.config/git-review/git-review.conf`
(Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.config\git-review\git-review.conf`)

With this content:

`[gerrit]
defaultremote = origin`

Answer (score 2):

*Adding some more data to pmitchell's answer.*

Navigate to the project you wish to use, and ensure you can connect to the Gerrit server:

```
$ cd <repo>
$ git review -s
```

You may get a warning like so:

```
No '.gitreview' file found in this repository.
We don't know where your gerrit is. Please manually create
a remote named gerrit and try again.
```

If so, you likely have your Gerrit review server’s “remote” called origin or something similar. You can check this like so:

```
$ git remote -v
```

You’ll likely get something like so, where the url points to a Gerrit project:

```
origin  <url> (fetch)
origin  <url> (push)
```

Assuming this is the case, just rename the remote:

```
$ git remote rename origin gerrit
```

If this isn’t (i.e. you have more than one remote), you may want to rename the relevant remote or add a new one for Gerrit:

```
$ git remote add gerrit [url]
```

**Reference:**
https://that.guru/blog/how-to-use-git-review/

Answer (score 1):

`git push` is a git command, and doesn't have anything to do with gerrit. The error you are seeing has to do with gerrit only, and it doesn't effect the other git commands, i.e. `git push`